# Anything faster than groupby for iterating through groups?

Tags: python, pandas

So I've narrowed down a previous problem down to this: I have a DataFrame that looks like this

```
              id  temp1  temp2
    9       10.0   True  False
    10      10.0   True  False
    11      10.0  False   True
    12      10.0  False   True
    17      15.0   True  False
    18      15.0   True  False
    19      15.0   True  False
    20      15.0   True  False
    21      15.0  False  False
    33      27.0   True  False
    34      27.0   True  False
    35      27.0  False   True
    36      27.0  False  False
    40      31.0   True  False
    41      31.0  False   True 
               .
               .
               .
```

and in reality, it's a few million lines long (and has a few other columns).

What I have it currently doing is

```
    grouped = coinc.groupby('id')
    final = grouped.filter(lambda x: ( x['temp2'].any() and x['temp1'].any()))
    lanif = final.drop(['temp1','temp2'],axis = 1 )
```

(coinc is the name of the dataframe)

which only keeps rows (grouped by id) if there is a true in both temp1 and temp2 for some rows with the same id. For example, with the above dataframe, it would get rid of rows with id 15, but keep everything else.

This, however, is deathly slow and I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `filter` with a lambda function here is slowing you down a lot.  You can speed things up by removing that.

---

```
u = coinc.groupby('id')
m = u.temp1.any() & u.temp2.any()
res = df.loc[coinc.id.isin(m[m].index), ['id']]
```

---

Comparing this to your approach on a larger frame.

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100_000)
b = np.random.randint(0, 2, 100_000, dtype=bool)
c = ~b

coinc = pd.DataFrame({'id': a, 'temp1': b, 'temp2': c})

In [295]: %%timeit
     ...: u = coinc.groupby('id')
     ...: m = u.temp1.any() & u.temp2.any()
     ...: res = coinc.loc[coinc.id.isin(m[m].index), ['id']]
     ...:
13.5 ms ± 476 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [296]: %%timeit
     ...: grouped = coinc.groupby('id')
     ...: final = grouped.filter(lambda x: ( x['temp2'].any() and x['temp1'].any()))
     ...: lanif = final.drop(['temp1','temp2'],axis = 1 )
     ...:
527 ms ± 7.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
np.array_equal(res.values, lanif.values)
```

```
True
```

Comment: Question: I did mine a little differently. Using your code, I'm finding that `.any()` executes a lot faster than `.agg(any)`. I thought they were comparable under the hood. Any thoughts as to why?

Answer (score 1):

```
i, u = pd.factorize(coinc.id)
t = np.zeros((len(u), 2), bool)
c = np.column_stack([coinc.temp1.to_numpy(), coinc.temp2.to_numpy()])

np.logical_or.at(t, i, c)

final = coinc.loc[t.all(1)[i], ['id']]

final

      id
9   10.0
10  10.0
11  10.0
12  10.0
33  27.0
34  27.0
35  27.0
36  27.0
40  31.0
41  31.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the groupby it's the lambda. Lambda operations are not vectorized*. You can get the same result faster using agg. I'd do:

```
 groupdf = coinc.groupby('id').agg(any)
 # Selects instance where both contain at least one true statement
 mask = maskdf[['temp1','temp2']].all(axis=1) 
 lanif = groupdf[mask].drop(['temp1','temp2'],axis = 1 )
```

*This is a pretty nuanced issue that I'm waaaay oversimplifying, sorry.

Comment: Disclaimer: I didn't test this code because I didn't have an easy way to enter sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative solution

```
f = coinc.groupby('id').transform('any')
result = coinc.loc[f['temp1'] & f['temp2'], coinc.columns.drop(['temp1', 'temp2'])]
```